# JQuery and strange behavior on hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a hover effect for all DIVs with `class="box"` on a page:

**Javascript**:

```
    JQ(".box").hover(function() {
        JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','visible');
    });

    JQ(".box").mouseleave(function(event) {
        JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','hidden');
    });
```

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE9 and Opera the `.tooltip` div disappears and re-appears continuously when the mouse moves within the boundaries of the .box DIV. 
any ideas why the hover function keeps being called for every pixel of the DIV?

You can see a working version [here](http://www.vildiridis-dimiourgiko.gr/itemlist.php?f=cat&fid=3&filter=typeid%7C6&show=default)

Comment: You're really on the right track, you just confused hover with mouseenter.

Comment: I've already tried mouseenter and it does the exact same thing :(

Answer (score 3):

When you only pass one function to `.hover()` that function is called when the mouse ***both*** enters and leaves.  So, you're making it visible on both entering and leaving which is conflicting with your mouseleave handler.

You could just do this:

```
JQ(".box").hover(function() {
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','visible');
}, function() {
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Or, a little more DRY (less repeated code):

```
JQ.fn.nextTip = function(vis) {
    return this.nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility', vis);
}

JQ(".box").hover(function() {
    JQ(this).nextTip('visible');
}, function() {
    JQ(this).nextTip('hidden');
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DkgVg/

Comment: Nice and clear explanation, useful to comprehend not only this problem but how the hover() function works. However, I tried your code (as well as the 2 other suggestions from Boz and User666) and I'm still getting the same behavior. I also tried using the display property instead of visibility with no luck.

Comment: @bikey77 - There's something else wrong with your code then that you aren't disclosing.  Did you remove the mouseleave code?  My answer works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DkgVg/.

Comment: @bikey77 - I added a fade option to the jsFiddle so you can see how that works too.

Comment: I have removed all other javascript and left only your code on my page and I've updated the files on the working demo in my first post. Please have a look for yourself and you will see that it doesn't work. Just to clarify, yes I used every method you and the other users suggested and also tried using the display property in css instead of visibility but yet the problem persists.

Comment: @bikey77 - your page uses `.mouseenter()`.  It should be using `.hover()`.  `.mouseenter()` does not support two functions being passed to it.  Only `.hover()` has that functionality.

Comment: I was experimenting with the code, I now have only hover() and like I said before, no matter what combination of js/css I tried the problem persists. Thank you for all the time you've put into my question, i appreciate it and I don't require you find the solution, I'm just mentioning the outcome of the various tests/changes I've committed.

Comment: @bikey77 - did you figure it out?  When I mouse around, I see things hiding and showing now.

Comment: The problem is with the overlapping divs and the hover or mouseenter event that should be associated with the div under the tooltip. For example, when you're hovering the 2nd item on the 2nd row and move right to the 3rd, the hovering wont trigger because the tooltip from #2 is still visible.

Comment: @bikey77 - I don't see that issue on my computer, but if you're seeing it, it's an issue with your design, not a coding issue per se.  You are covering up a hover target with your temporary display.  You may be able to work around it with a neutral area (margin, padding on container div) between the two so that you have to leave the first hover (causing the temporary content to go away) before you can hover over the neighboring items.  Or, display your temporary content differently that doesn't obscure the hover targets.

Comment: @bikey77 - Your design is flawed.  The `.tooltip` object cannot cover the item you are hovering over or you lose the hover as soon as you display it.  Change the design so the tooltip object does not overlap the `boxwrapper` object being hovered.

Answer (score 1):

You should try replacing the `hover` part with:

```
JQ(".box").mouseenter(function() {
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Or keep `hover` and do:

```
JQ(".box").hover(function() {
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','visible');
}, function(){
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I regret to say that it didn't resolve the issue though...

Answer (score 0):

Just stop execution of event functions for this jQuery object

```
JQ(".box").hover(function() {
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").stop(true,true).css('visibility','visible');
}, function(){
    JQ(this).nextAll(".tooltip:first").stop(true,true).css('visibility','hidden');
});
```